# How to figure out melodies of a different timbre than the piano

Tags: ear-training

I am trying to develop my aural abilities, I'm trying to figure out the melody lines of songs by ear. I tried one-note tracing(i.e. one unknown note played on the piano and then I have to figure out on my piano which note was played). Although I have gotten a little bit of accuracy in this exercise, I am not able to replicate this when figuring out a pop song with vocal melody lines. I think it probably has to do with the fact that it's a different timbre, so I struggle a little. So, I would like advice on how I can overcome this problem, any feedback or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not certain what the question is here.

Comment: Are the answers here helpful: [How do I identify the first 4 notes in this song?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/4470/70803).

Comment: I think I'll change it to make it a little more specific

Comment: I think the issue with this question is the use of the word timbre.  It the question how to hear a melody of a different timbre, or how to get past the first note of a melody of any timbre?

Answer (score 1):

### Practice what you're aiming for

A typical feature of **conservatory** ear training is **piano melodic dictation exercises**. If that's what you're used to, it makes sense that you won't be as good at figuring the **pitch** of different sorts of sounds.

If it's **vocal** music you can't figure out (which can be very **microtonally rich**), then I can't think of a faster way to get better than to keep trying - your ear will eventually adapt.

Common tricks you might have used when listening to piano pieces still apply, such as keeping track of the **chord progressions**, and figuring out what "fits", as well as using the **accompaniment** notes to **track intervals** (like **solving for x** in a simple math equation).

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Learn scales and arpeggios. Establish which notes go with which chords, and where the **root** of a key is in all that (^1 in a root chord, ^5 in a IV chord). As with everything, the more you do, the better you become at it - it will take some time!

Learn to recognise intervals - not necessarily by name, but be able to reproduce any interval you hear - facilitated by knowing those scales and arpeggios.

Answer (score 0):

I would begin by listening to vocal and instrumental versions of the same song. This would be an exercise in itself — listening to multiple versions to hear the same melody in different timbres.

As a next step, find a song where one version has a piano melody and one has a vocal melody. Transcribe the piano melody, then play along with the vocal melody (you may have to transpose your piano version, which is also a good ear-training exercise).

I suggest children's songs and folk songs as a starting point. These are most likely to have been recorded both with voice and with other instruments.